# Associative array doubts for vote count

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am storing vote count on vote action as

```
//after vote action triggered 
 if ($count == '') { //for first time

                    $count = '1';
                   } else { // after fisrt time
                   $count ++
                    }
```

This is fine. Now i want to calculate how many vote per day so i thought to store the date along with the count from that i can calculate number of votes per day, So i thought to use associative array but now what i afraid is same date multiple vote will come,

How can i store **date as key because key may become duplicate** i believe.

If i do like this

```
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $value = 1;
    $count = array($today => $value);
```

Is there any way to store it multiple time as a dynamic array with date?

If it is single value then we can store dynamically using `$arrayname []` but for associative how can i accomplish without making key problem as key may contain same date ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you won't actually use the date function and that you are processing some data or something. Otherwise it's very unlikely that your array will ever get larger that one item long unless your PHP script runs for a very long time.

```
<?php

$count = array();

.....

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$count[ $date ] = array_key_exists( $date, $count ) ? $count[ $date ] + 1 : 1;
```